# how to get JSON array from JSON object in angularJS

Tags: javascript

i get json object data of the following form from a backend server:

```
{
"Transactions":
[
    {
        "category":"phone",
        "title":"title1"
    },

    {
        "category":"phone",
        "title":"Iphone"
    }

] }
```

I want to convert the above json object into json array of the form:

```
[
    {
        "category":"phone",
        "title":"title1"
    },

    {
        "category":"phone",
        "title":"Iphone"
    },

    {   
        "category":"phone",
        "title":"title2"
    }
]
```

thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

```
jsonData = {"Transactions":
    [
        {
            "category":"phone",
            "title":"title1"
        },
        {
            "category":"phone",
            "title":"Iphone"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Just access it from `jsonData.Transactions` as that is where the array is stored.

Comment: Hello man, thank you for your answer; i tried to use your code like this:

$http.get('someserver url').success(function(data) {
$scope.phones = data.Transactions;

but it did not work, any suggestions

Comment: Try logging to the console with `console.log(data)` or `alert(data)`

Comment: after enabling CORS on the backend server, it worked perfectly, thank you a lot.